# Transferring data from one sheet to another using a single script

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have a problem where I need to transfer the cell data from one sheet to another. What I'm trying to achieve in the end is that if I click a button, it will transfer my data from the sheet I'm on to the sheet I'd like it to go to.

My use for this sheet is to take the data of one product (beer) and move it to another location (another tank). As we move the beer from tank to tank, the data needs to move with it).

I've set up several buttons on the page that can be linked to scripts. So let's say I'm in the sheet for "Tank 1" and I need to transfer the information to "Tank 2", I need a way for the data to shift from one sheet to the other. I don't need it to erase the data as I've already inserted a "Clear Data" button onto the page.

If possible, it would also be extremely beneficial if there was some kind of warning before the script was initiated. Some kind of (are you sure you want to do that?" type of message.

I have tried using the IMPORTRANGE function but I'm not sure how to program it for a script. I apologize for my ignorance in this but I'm new to coding.

I very much appreciate any help with this and if you're ever in Finland, please stop by for some beers.

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow Max. 
Could you please provide some code ? We can't help you if we don't see what you already did.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I figured it out. I'm using this and it seems to work for now.

```
function C1() {
  var sourceSheet  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("C1");

var destSheet  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  sourceSheet.getRange("A1:I43").copyTo(destSheet.getRange("A1:I43"), {contentsOnly:true});
}
```